# Soap API XML issue using nusoap?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I have created SOAP API using nusoap in php.Everything is working fine. I have one file **service.php** when I hit this file I get documentation like this.

[image: My screenshot]

If I hit this url:

[Other Screenshot](https://www.eway.com.au/gateway/ManagedPaymentService/managedCreditCardPayment.asmx?op=ProcessPayment)
[image: OTHER]

I get a diffrent type of xml document.

Why this is so different?

code for **service.php**

```
<?php
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";
require_once "functions.php";
$server=new nusoap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("SOAP", "urn:SOAP");
$server->register("addRecord",
        array("fname"=>"xsd:string","lname"=>"xsd:string","buis_name"=>"xsd:string","phone_num"=>"xsd:int","city"=>"xsd:string","state"=>"xsd:string",           "zipcode"=>"xsd:int","email"=>"xsd:string"
        ,"w_store"=>"xsd:string","con_store"=>"xsd:string","ind_store"=>"xsd:string","gas_staion"=>"xsd:string","other"=>"xsd:string"),
        array("return" => "xsd:string"),
        "urn:SOAP",
       "urn:SOAPn#addRecord",
       "rpc",
       "encoded",
      "Add user information to database");
 $server->register("checkLogin",
        array("email"=>"xsd:string","password"=>"xsd:string"),
        array("return" => "xsd:string"),
        "urn:SOAP",
       "urn:SOAP#checkLogin",
       "rpc",
       "encoded",
      "Verify UserLogin"); 
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA=isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);


?>
```

Comment: your links don't work

Comment: please copy and paste your code in your actual post when asking a question, as it is both easier for those hoping to assist you, and also the links may expire providing no benefit to people who find your question in the future.

Comment: for me it is working. i don't have enough reputation to post images?

Comment: You need to share the code which is handling that action

Comment: Please check now guys.. @Alex

Comment: Please check @nomistic

Comment: @Soma shared check out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you send soap request from the client.Then print all the request & response.Then you will get the desired result.